# About Sultan Khan

Tags: famous-players

I know the standard facts about Sultan khan's life. He was servant to a wealthy Indian military guy who let him play in tournaments whenever he traveled to England. Sultan Khan was a really strong player who originally had learned to play with slightly different rules (about promotion and stalemate eg). He won the British Championship and defeated Marshall, Flohr, and Capablanca. When players were invited to his masters house, Sultan Khan was expected to serve them, even though he was their better at chess!

What I am looking for is the lesser known facts about him. Any picture, story, or other reference is welcome. Please quote your sources.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mir_Sultan_Khan

Comment: Yep, checked that a long time ago. I am looking for more in-depth, difficult-to-find bits of arcana.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lots of info, pictures, and fun facts here:
http://www.chesshistory.com/winter/extra/sultankhan.html